# Autodesk maya 2014 animation loop (graphic editor), doesnt seem to loop the whole animation

Tags: animation, maya

I´m struggling with a assignment, where I need to animate a robot to walk. The animation is done, however now I need to make it loop, so it seems he is walking for a long time. I'm using  the graphic editor, however something seems to be wrong. When I try to set the loop, some of the animation seems to be left out, and the robot begins to walk really awkwardly after the first 33 frames. Here is a video of the robot.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e3-EZo8tmx0

Not sure whats causing it, do you have a clue? :)

here is the graphic editor with all the keyframes selected: 
[image: http://i.imgur.com/umuvFst.png]

Comment: Welcome to [so]. This question is off-topic here because it's not related to programming. Please go through the [help/on-topic]. This question could be asked at [graphicdesign.se].

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a better question for [area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5022/3d-graphics).

However if you look at your curves in the editor you can see that several of them are not looping properly - the sawtooth pattern where a given curve shows a smooth change followed by an almost vertical section in every loop is the giveaway.  There is at least one on the green (Y) and another on the  blue (Z) axis visible in your sample image - however there's no way to tell from the screen shot which curves they are. Look at each channel in isolation and spot the uneven repeats and you can fix your problem - it's likely that you a mix of keys that are 1 complete cycle apart and others that are 1.5 cycles apart, it's easy for that to happen when you leave auto key turned on.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you did not select all your appropriate channels when you applied the loop/cycle. Can't really tell from the Graph Editor shot you posted, but check to make sure all the robots appendages are properly keyed after the point below.

[image]